# Flyway - migration file name length limit?

Tags: database-migration, flyway

I noticed that when I created migration file with very long description in file name then it is omitted by flyway. There are no logs regarding the file, I'd expect at least some error on console.

I'm going through [docs](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/concepts/migrations.html#naming-1) but I cannot find any mention regarding migration file name size.

I'm working on windows so maybe there are some system limitations.

If there is indeed such a limit then please reference me to proper sources.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely restriction you're running up against is the description (the part of the filename missing the `V1__` version and `.sql` suffix) goes into a fixed size field in the history table. That insert may fail if the file name is too long. What file name do you not see?

If you run with full debug `-X` do you see any errors?

Comment: I just checked and no, there are no errors. How can I check flyway history table in oracle database?

Comment: It will (unless you've configured it otherwise) be called `flyway_schema_history` in your default schema.

Comment: Could you share the migration file - or at least the file name?

Comment: Sorry for late response: so file which didn't work was `Vxx.xx.xx.xxx__xxx-Alter-SomeTablName-Drop-FieldName.sql` and it starter working after I updated it to `Vxx.xx.xx.xxx__xxx-Drop-SomeTablName-FieldName.sql` (these names correspond to exact original file names length). I also checked flyway table `schema_version`, it has field `description` with type `nvarchar 200`.

Comment: That's odd - I can't explain why there was a problem unless your change happened to bring it under the 200 character limit.